# "There is an issue with this product mapping" message

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, category

I am working on a site that seems to be working correctly, except for the drop-down lists on the category view pages.   Both the sorting drop down and the items per page drop down result in a pop up error message:  "There is an issue with this product mapping, please contact the administrators"   This is a fairly straight forward site with only a small number of third party extensions.   I have been looking for a solution, but have not found one.   I might be overlooking something obvious.   Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't appear to be a core Magento error message, it most likely is coming from one of the third party extensions.

You can start by disabling all of the non-core modules and seeing if the error still exists.

Here's a good place to start debugging: [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429)